# Difficulty understanding the "_n_" variable in SAS, and how it applies to a concatenate function

Tags: sas

I am very new to SAS, and for whatever reason am finding a lot of difficulty deciphering what this code block (below) does. I've googled and search stackoverflow to no avail. I'd appreciate any input, thanks!

```
set dataset;
id=cat("L",_n_);
run;
```

Comment: In this usage, one way to consider it is as a row number but it actually represents the number of loops of the data step. In more complex data steps they will differ, but in your example/usage row number is a good analogy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably there must be a `data` statement as well.

```
data newdataset;
   set dataset;
   id = cat("L", _n_);
run;
```

This above code creates a new dataset named  `newdataset` from the existing dataset named `dataset`.

Also creating a new column called `id`, and `id` is creating by concatenating a constant character value "L" with the automatic variable `_n_` using the `CAT` function.  The automatic variable `_n_` represents the number of times the DATA step has iterated.

Comment: Yep I missed the data statement. So for the resulting column id, are all of the values "L"? Or do they count, for example if the dataset has 10 rows, the last row would have a value of L10 in the id column?

Comment: @jschol30 run the code and check the output. SAS is online/cloud for free for learning.